# Auto updater file deleted by certain antivirus

Tags: windows, vb.net, antivirus

I am currently developing apps with a capability to auto-update app with the newest app found on the server. Here is the common logic:

- Client's app will have version.txt to save the latest version installed on the client.
- Server have its version.txt to provide information of the latest version delivered and it is shared through windows file sharing.
- I have an apps named "update.exe" which would check the version.txt on the server by reading the version.txt and compare it to the local version.txt. If the version is different, update.exe will rename my apps from "myapp.exe" to "b_myapp.exe" for backup purpose. update.exe will copy the "myapp.exe" from the server to the local folder. After copying file, it will validate the "myapp.exe" with the server "myapp.exe". If the file doesn't match, it will delete and retry for several times and if it is failed for 3 times, it will copy back "b_myapp.exe" to "myapp.exe" and say "update fail. please contact customer support". If it is validated, "update.exe" will delete the "b_myapp.exe", update the version.txt to the latest and run "myapp.exe".

This might not the best on implementing auto update. But we have implemented this method for years and have no problem on any antivirus until recently it was reported that Kapersky antivirus treat updated "update.exe" and "myapp.exe" as risk.

Executing "update.exe" will prompt Kapersky alert on unwanted apps and you have only 2 option which is do not run and disinfect and restart the apps. If you chose disinfect, it will remove the "myapp.exe" and re-run the "setup.exe" (installation file) and do a repair which cause the apps to return to the oldest version. If you chose Do Not Run option, it will delete the "myapp.exe" and if you re-run the apps, it will call "setup.exe" and do repair. So choosing option 1 or 2 will result the same.

I have scanned "myapp.exe" seperately on the server and there is no infection. I copy the file manually from File Sharing to the local computer, and it automatically deleted by AV after several seconds.

What I did:
- Add the folder into the whitelist on Kapersky Anti Virus
- Add "update.exe" and "myapp.exe" into the trusted application list.

And it didn't deleted but it also not executed.

FYI, the AV has been installed for several months and had no problem until quite recent.

Any advice on how to implement auto update on VB.NET (or should I change the "update.exe" to other language)? Or any advice that my apps can be whitelist from Kapersky AV?

Comment: Have you contacted Kapersky about the false positive?

Comment: Probably signing your executables with [Authenticode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/authenticode) would improve this.

Comment: @Richard I haven't contacted Kapersky and would try to contact Kapersky.

Comment: @UweKeim Thanks. I will look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried what @Uwe Keim suggested by signing the executeables and indeed it solved.